# How to properly cite/include meeting discussion in a doctoral thesis?

Tags: citations

I am going to have a private meeting with an institution next month, and I would like to use what will be said there as a reference in my doctoral thesis.

What would be the most appropriate way to do this?

I thought about taking detailed notes, or even recording the meeting (with the consent of everyone involved) so to be able to transcribe it and include the transcription as an appendix, after allowing the other participants to review the notes/transcription to correct eventual mistakes.

Are there other alternatives? Is this somewhat usual?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. What sort of things will be said there that they make sense to reference in a thesis?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it is a thesis in engineering based on a project in industry. The meeting will discuss the boundaries within which the experimental project will have to move and thus it is highly likely that some challenges that I will have to solve/cope with will come from the meeting, and not only from "simple" physics.

Comment: I fail to see how a transcription will be beneficial, much less needed. All studies have constraints on them. Everyone will understand.

Comment: @JonCuster I thought it might be needed to provide a valid reference that is not otherwise available to the reader.

Comment: You can certainly record, with permission, and transcribe.  Transcribing is a lot of work but it can be quite helpful.  You might end up quoting portions of the transcript.  You might put the whole audio recording online, or certain excerpts.  The results will be better if people talk one at a time -- a talking stick might help, or a hand signal from an assertive member of the group who isn't at the forefront of the discussion; the hand signal would be given whenever two people are talking at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the citation rules for "personal communication" for whatever reference style you are using. This would include meetings etc.